# Bring two vectors in the same length

Tags: matlab, interpolation, downsampling

I have the following problem:

I have two data vectors **v1** (Length **N1=13812**) and **v2** (Length **N2=60002021**). I have to bring both vectors in the same length **N3** using interpolation bzw. downsampling, with the requirement: **2xN1.**

Can somebody help me? My idea was to use: **interp**, **interp1** and downsample to solve to problem. Is that the right approach?

Comment: you just need `interp1` or `interp2` depends on your dimension

Comment: here's an example why you shouldn't use interp1 to downsample a signal: t = 1:0.01:30; x=sin(t); plot(1:3:30, interp1(t, x, 1:3:30), 'o-'); hold on; plot(t, x); hold off

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your signal and sampling rate, using `interp1` might not be the right thing to do.
There is a `resample` function that you could use like this:

```
v1_resampled = resample(v1, 2, 1);
v2_resampled = resample(v2, p, q);
```

where the parameters `p`, `q` depending on the sampling rate of your vector `v2`.

Always check the beginning / end of the resampled vectors. Check NaNs and be careful if you have non equidistant sampling.

Another possible alternative would be to use a moving average / moving median filter on the higher resolution signal. The best resampling approach really depends on the signal type.

Comment: `resample` requires the Signal Processing Toolbox.